# Is 'stolen' used as an adjective or noun?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, past-participles, modifiers

**Stolen** is past participle of 'steal' but is it used as an adjective or noun! I couldn't find anything on the net. just this:

> The 71-year-old then allegedly tried to return the **stolen** items for cash or store credit on the same day.

or in a movie

> Please insert your **stolen** card now.

Comment: Why do you think it might be used as a noun? It isn't in either of your examples.

Comment: Many participles are adjectives for example, stolen.

Comment: It's neither an adjective nor a noun. It's a verb phrase headed by a past-participle form of verb. It's function is modifier.

Comment: Would you give me the link on the net for your say? because I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: It is a past participle verb modifying the noun "items". Compare "the snoring man", "the sleeping baby" and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Both participles, past and present, can modify nouns.

If the underlying verb is transitive, the noun so modified is in the state conferred by the action of the verb when completed:

> They sat on the newly **painted** bench.
>
> They tried to force open the **locked** door.

If the underlying verb is intransitive, the noun so modified has attained and is in the state which results from the action of the verb when underway:

> They entered the building through the **revolving** door.
>
> They sat a little distance away from the **smoking** campfire.
>
> They heard **running** water.

Answer (score 0):

The past participle in the sentence presented is a modifier. It modifies the noun items.  In other words, this modifier functions as an adjective. So you can also call it an adjective.

It's not a noun.